# Compute indices of two vectors' common elements efficiently

Tags: c++, vector, unordered-set

I have two vectors (each of them have only unique elements) that share a set of integers. I would like to compute the indices of the elements of one vector that also exist in the other vector as efficiently as possible. Can you outperform my humble inefficient implementation?

**Edit:**
The vectors are not sorted and we need the indices of the unsorted vector. Furthermore, it is forbidden to modify the initial vectors (`random_vec_1` and `random_vec_2`) when solving the problem.

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <set>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <vector>

using namespace std::chrono;

int main() {

    // Setup 1: Construct two vectors with random integers.
    constexpr size_t num = 1000;

    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(0, num);

    std::vector<int> random_vec_1;
    std::vector<int> random_vec_2;
    random_vec_1.reserve(num);
    random_vec_2.reserve(num);
    for (size_t i = 0u; i < num; ++i) {
        random_vec_1.push_back(dis(gen));
        random_vec_2.push_back(dis(gen));
    }
    // Setup 2: Make elements unique and shuffle them.
    std::set<int> s1(random_vec_1.begin(), random_vec_1.end());
    std::set<int> s2(random_vec_2.begin(), random_vec_2.end());
    random_vec_1.assign(s1.begin(), s1.end());
    random_vec_2.assign(s2.begin(), s2.end());
    std::random_shuffle(random_vec_1.begin(), random_vec_1.end());
    std::random_shuffle(random_vec_2.begin(), random_vec_2.end());


    std::cout << "size random_vec_1: " << random_vec_1.size() << "\n";
    std::cout << "size random_vec_2: " << random_vec_2.size() << "\n";

    auto begin1 = high_resolution_clock::now();

    // Solve problem -------------------------------------------
    std::vector<size_t> match_index_2;
    std::unordered_set<int> my_set(random_vec_1.begin(), random_vec_1.end());
    for (size_t i = 0u; i < random_vec_2.size(); ++i) {
        if (my_set.count(random_vec_2[i]) == 1u)
            match_index_2.push_back(i);
    }
    // ---------------------------------------------------------

    auto end1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto ticks1 = duration_cast<microseconds>(end1-begin1);
    std::cout << "Set approach took " << ticks1.count() << " microseconds.\n";
    std::cout << "Number of common indices: " << match_index_2.size() << "\n";

}
```

Comment: Have a look at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/includes

Comment: Also: You might consider the example at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique

Comment: @DieterLücking These links do not help. `std::includes` tells you if the second range is **included** in the first range, which is unrelated. `std::unique` removes **consecutive** duplicates from **one** range, which is even more unrelated.

Comment: The vectors are **not sorted** for my real problem.

Comment: Set Intersections (not includes) is:  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection

Comment: Another detail about the problem: Is the range of values *really* limited to [0,1000)? Solving the problem for a small range has different optimal solutions than the case of unlimited range.

Comment: @user2079303: In my case, I care mostly about vector sizes up to 1000 elements (after making them unique). But it would be nice to know which solution works best for which sizes for other people having the same question.

Comment: @MrX I was referring to the range values that the integers may have, not the number of elements in the vectors (although that is also relevant).

Comment: @user2079303: My brain is malfunctioning today... It should be fast for arbitrary unsigned integer values (yes, I used integers in my example for no specific reason).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vector` are so fast nowadays that I would not use a `set`:

1. Copy the first vector to e.g. `new_vector_1`;
2. Sort `new_vector_1`;
3. Use `binary_search` to find value in `new_vector_1`.

**Code:**

```
std::vector<int> new_vec_1(random_vec_1);
std::sort(std::begin(new_vec_1), std::end(new_vec_1));
std::vector<size_t> match_index_2;
match_index_2.reserve(random_vec_2.size());

for (size_t i = 0; i < random_vec_2.size(); ++i) {
    if (std::binary_search(std::begin(new_vec_1), 
                           std::end(new_vec_1),
                           random_vec_2[i])) {
        match_index_2.push_back(i);
    }
}
```

See code on [ideone](http://ideone.com/58qnPf) - Code is twice as fast as the `set` version, and I think it may be optimize further.

Note that this code is algorithmically equivalent to yours, but `std::vector` are so fast you get better performance.

---

Here is another approach that sort both vectors (but is a bit faster):

```
std::vector<int> new_vec_1(random_vec_1);
std::vector<int> new_vec_2(random_vec_2);
std::sort(std::begin(new_vec_1), std::end(new_vec_1));
std::sort(std::begin(new_vec_2), std::end(new_vec_2));
std::vector<size_t> match_index_2;
match_index_2.reserve(random_vec_2.size());

for (auto it1 = new_vec_1.begin(), it2 = new_vec_2.begin();
     it1 != new_vec_1.end() && it2 != new_vec_2.end();
     ++it2) {
    while (it1 != new_vec_1.end() && *it1 < *it2) ++it1;
    if (it1 != new_vec_1.end() && *it1 == *it2) {
        match_index_2.push_back(it2 - new_vec_2.begin());
    }
}
```

Comment: On my machine this is faster than my approach if the vector is relatively small. If the vector size is larger than (e.g.) 6000 than the set approach seems to be slightly faster.

Comment: @MrX I get better result with vector (twice as fast) for size up to `100000` (final size after removing duplicates ~60k), I did not test above. Did you compile with optimization flag (`-O3`) on?

Comment: Oh, you are right! I forgot the optimization flag. It is not twice as fast for me but still significantly faster for the size range I care about.

Comment: I am not convinced that reserve is appropriate here because we don't exactly know the size. Anyway, I marked this as answer because it is short, has a small description and is at least as fast as other solutions (up to this point).

Answer (score 1):

### New answer

The new requirement is that the original vectors cannot be modified when computing the solution. The sorting-intersection solution does not work anymore since the indices are mixed up.

Here is what I suggest : mapping the first vector values to the corresponding indices with an `unordered_map`, and then running through the second vector values.

```
// Not necessary, might increase performance
match_index_2.reserve(std::min(random_vec_1.size(), random_vec_2.size()));

std::unordered_map<int, int> index_map;
// random_vec_2 is the one from which we want the indices.
index_map.reserve(random_vec_2.size());
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < random_vec_2.size(); ++i) {
    index_map.emplace(random_vec_2[i], i);
}

for (auto& it : random_vec_1) {
    auto found_it = index_map.find(it);
    if (found_it != index_map.end()) {
        match_index_2.push_back(found_it->second);
    }
}
```

Also, if the values in your vectors are inside a relatively small range (which is what user2079303 asked you), you can replace the map with a vector, which might further increase performance. In the following, I assume the values are inside the range [0, num].

```
match_index_2.reserve(std::min(random_vec_1.size(), random_vec_2.size()));

constexpr std::size_t unmapped = -1; // -1 or another unused index
// Since std::size_t is an unsigned type, -1 will actually be the maximum value it can hold.

std::vector<std::size_t> index_map(num, unmapped);
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < random_vec_2.size(); ++i) {
    index_map[random_vec_2[i]] = i;
}

for (auto& it : random_vec_1) {
    auto index = index_map[it];
    if (index != unmapped) {
        match_index_2.push_back(index);
    }
}
```

### Previous answer

Since your vectors are already sorted (after using `std::set` to keep unique elements), you can use this algorithm :

```
auto first1 = random_vec_1.begin();
auto last1 = random_vec_1.end();
auto first2 = random_vec_2.begin();
auto last2 = random_vec_2.end();
auto index_offset = first1; // Put first2 if you want the indices of the second vector instead

while (first1 != last1 && first2 != last2)
    if (*first1 < *first2)
        ++first1;
    else if (*first2 < *first1)
        ++first2;
    else {
        match_index_2.push_back(std::distance(index_offset, first1));
        ++first1;
        ++first2;
    }
}
```

Adapted from [the gcc libstdc++ source code for std::set_intersection](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-3.4/stl__algo_8h-source.html#l04195).

Here is another version, adapted from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection) :

```
auto first1 = random_vec_1.begin();
auto last1 = random_vec_1.end();
auto first2 = random_vec_2.begin();
auto last2 = random_vec_2.end();
auto index_offset = first1; // Put first2 if you want the indices of the second vector instead

while (first1 != last1 && first2 != last2) {
    if (*first1 < *first2) {
        ++first1;
    } else  {
        if (!(*first2 < *first1)) {
            match_index_2.push_back(std::distance(index_offset, first1++));
        }
        ++first2;
    }
}
```

If you want more efficiency, call `reserve` on `match_index_2` before. Also, you can get rid of sets by using `std::sort` and `std::unique` instead.

```
// Setup 2: Make elements unique.
auto first1 = random_vec_1.begin();
auto last1 = random_vec_1.end();
std::sort(first1, last1);
last1 = std::unique(first1, last1);
random_vec_1.erase(last1, random_vec_1.end());

auto first2 = random_vec_2.begin();
auto last2 = random_vec_2.end();
std::sort(first2, last2);
last2 = std::unique(first2, last2);
random_vec_2.erase(last2, random_vec_2.end());
```

Comment: In general, the vectors that I deal with are not sorted. I just had to construct a toy example and used `std::set` for that.

Comment: @MrX You say in your edit that you need the indices of the unsorted vector. But your current solution sorts your vectors. So, is sorting ok or do you want the original vectors untouched ? I'm taking a wild guess here, but I doubt that another algorithm beats sorting and using `set_intersection`.

Comment: @MrX Nelxiost's makes a good point, your requirements conflict with what your solution currently does. Nelxiost: `set_intersection` gives you the values common to both sorted ranges, not the indices of one vector, and that also contradicts the requirements.

Comment: My solution (not the setup) works also for unsorted vectors. I just added a random_shuffle for the problem setup to make it more clear.

Comment: My bad. I edited so that you get the indices instead of the values. I deleted the part with `set_intersection` since you cannot use it for the problem (except maybe by creating a special output iterator). @MrX You didn't answer. Do you require the original vectors to remain unsorted ?

Comment: @Nelxiost: Yes, they have to remain unsorted. In fact, I am not allowed to modify the original vectors. Will add it to the question.

Comment: @MrX Edited. I cannot test the new code at the moment, though. It might be bugged.

Comment: Great! Debugged and test: performs comparable to @Host's solution.

Comment: @MrX Glad to hear it. I added a version where the range of values is known (and relatively small) : what user2079303 was asking about. Hopefully I also corrected the code.

Comment: Not yet bug-free: Your second for loop is not correct. You should use iterators and not range-based foor loop. Also, the mapped type is size_t and I would avoid the variable name `map` since some use `using namespace std` and then map is a keyword because of `std::map`.

Comment: @MrX I don't see how the loop is incorrect. `it` contains successive values in `random_vec_1`, and I indexed `map` with the values of `random_vec_2`. Thus, `map[it]` gives the index in `random_vec_2` of the value `it` (if it is mapped). The mapped type is indeed `size_t` since it is the type of indices. As to the name `map`... I never use `using namespace std`, exactly for the reason you stated. Anyway, I edited it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114643/discussion-between-mrx-and-nelxiost).

Answer (score 1):

You might create indices into the sets of values and operate on these:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

inline std::vector<std::size_t>  make_unique_sorted_index(const std::vector<int>& v) {
    std::vector<std::size_t> result(v.size());
    std::iota(result.begin(), result.end(), 0);
    std::sort(result.begin(), result.end(),
        [&v] (std::size_t a, std::size_t b) {
            return v[a] < v[b];
    });
    auto obsolete = std::unique(result.begin(), result.end(),
        [&v] (std::size_t a, std::size_t b) {
            return v[a] == v[b];
    });
    result.erase(obsolete, result.end());
    return result;
}

// Constructs an unordered range of indices [i0, i1, i2, ...iN) into the first set
// for elements that are found uniquely in both sets.
// Note: The sequence [set1[i0], set1[i1], set1[i2], ... set1[iN]) will be sorted.
std::vector<std::size_t>  unordered_set_intersection(
    const std::vector<int>& set1,
    const std::vector<int>& set2)
{
    std::vector<std::size_t> result;
    result.reserve(std::min(set1.size(), set2.size()));
    std::vector<std::size_t> index1 = make_unique_sorted_index(set1);
    std::vector<std::size_t> index2 = make_unique_sorted_index(set2);

    auto i1 = index1.begin();
    auto i2 = index2.begin();
    while(i1 != index1.end() && i2 != index2.end()) {
        if(set1[*i1] < set2[*i2]) ++i1;
        else if(set2[*i2] < set1[*i1]) ++i2;
        else {
            result.push_back(*i1);
            ++i1;
            ++i2;
        }
    }
    result.shrink_to_fit();
    return result;
}
```

Note: An improvement in performance might be gained by skipping the second index and operating on a copy of the second set.

Alternatively, `make_unique_sorted_index` might be replaced by:

```
inline std::vector<std::size_t>  make_sorted_index(const std::vector<int>& v) {
    std::vector<std::size_t> result(v.size());
    std::iota(result.begin(), result.end(), 0);
    std::sort(result.begin(), result.end(),
        [&v] (std::size_t a, std::size_t b) {
            return v[a] < v[b];
    });
    return result;
}
```

The algorithm produces stable results if the indices are unique or not:

- The sorting of elements (the result indices pointing to) is as stable as std::sort.
- If the indices are not unique, the number of identical elements (the result indices pointing to) is the minimum number of identical elements in the first or second set, respectively.

Comment: I would use const ref arguments for unordered_set_intersection but otherwise looks nice. Still, it's a little bit slower than @Holt's solution.

Comment: @MrX Sure - Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In reality I would expect sorting the vectors to substantially outperform the creation of the `std::set`, because the STL-set is a tree, and a `vector` of `int` can be sorted in linear time using counting sort, which, if you don't count beyond one, will give you a set. Creating the set is O(n log n) for n insertions of cost log n, whereas the sort is O(n), as mentioned.

On the sorted vector, you can then run `std::set_difference`, which should also run in time linear to the larger of the two inputs.

Thus you should be able to do this in linear time.

If you cannot modify the vector you can use a hashmap (std::unordered_map) to map values to indices in the original vector. Note that since you did not mention the numbers being unique, you would find a result such as the values x_1,...,x_n are contained in both sets, and then you would use the map to project that back to indices in your original vector using the hashmap.

Comment: Counting sort only applies to ranges of small values. MrX does use a quite small range (0...1000), but it might be worth noting to users who may not have the liberty to make such assumption. The upper bound for *general* sorting of a vector is also O(n log n).

Comment: Using a hashmap as the counter, you can apply this for fairly large ranges (2^xxx) too, as long as they are sparse enough. Of course the memory cost is linear to the size of the universe of symbols (numbers), but more often than not that works out. For all ints for example you can count up to 2^32 occurrences in 16GB of memory. Since OP wants a set, he actually just needs one bit to indicate existence/absence, which means he would need 2^32 bit, which is 2^29 Byte, i.e. ~512MB memory.